# Write number formating in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Have a bit of code ported from VB6 to VB.NET. It uses `Write` and `WriteLine` all the way to produce output files.

Now, I need to compare outputs from original and ported code, but there's one tiny problem with number formatting. For instance whereas VB6 code `Write`s just `.5`, the VB.NET code produces `0.5`, instead of `.0005` (in original) it writes `5E-4`, etc.

How can I make VB.NET's `Write` to write numbers in the same format as VB6? The option of refactoring writing code to include formatting step is not acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.NET, you could use the String.Format function in your Write/WriteLine calls.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:c}", price))
```

More information on formatting strings can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x.aspx).

Comment: By the way, `Console.WriteLine` already has a overload that does the same as String.Format.

Comment: Thanks, but the code does not write to Console, it writes to files with `FileSystem.WriteLine` routine, an it does not have formatting options. 

Also, changing all calls from `Write(handle, arg)` to `Write(handle, String.Format("{0:c}", arg))` is the last option as I have too many `Write` and `WriteLine` calls.

Answer (score 0):

- Write and WriteLine are *normally* used with Input and LineInput therefore the data should still be able to be read and written in the same fashion.
- If you are doing this because the output is for a third party program then you may just have to bite the bullet and search and replace using a simple recorded macro (Ctrl+Shift+R) or search and replace using (Ctrl+H).  Neither of these is very difficult!
- Welcome to .NET! When you say you *ported from VB6 to VB.NET* that means using new concepts and adapting new methods of doing things.  Simply running the built in upgrade is *not* porting to .NET!
- You might try something along the lines of `Write(handle, arg.ToString("#.####"))` instead of the aforementioned String.Format call.
- You don't mention the reason *why* you need the data written in the same fashion as earlier?
- *Refactoring code is not acceptable*..... hrm... care to explain that one?  (If it's anything but laziness, people will listen.)

Comment: Converting a solution with 20K lines from VB to VB.NET is not as trivial as it would seem, thus I called it "porting".

Comment: By saying that *refactoring is not acceptable* I meant that I don't have time to go though every call to `Write` and `WriteLine` and change it to `Write(handle, arg.ToString("#.####"))` to achieve a minor benefit.

Comment: @zzandy - Not sure of the purpose of your first comment, but I have ported VB6 project with > 100k lines to .NET.  Your second comment could be accomplished in a matter of seconds with a macro recorded in Visual Studio.  Have you have ever recorded a macro in VS?

Comment: @roygbiv - Stack Overflow does not allow paragraphs in comments, so I used two comments where I normally would use two paragraphs. When you were porting that solution to VB.NET what tools did you used? I ran some free conversion tool (can't find it now) and than had spent a week or so to make it even compile. No I haven't recorded any macros for VS. The task it not relevant anymore, but I'll try macro.